# Strange error on GetItems. Missing parameter depending on Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, lookup-column, flow, power-automate

Given: 2 lists (1 calendar, 1 custom list).
Calendar has a lookup column to custom list.
Within a flow I want to retrieve all items from the calendar which have the lookup column set to a certain element from the custom list.

I use GetItems and do an ODATA-filtering. In most cases it does what I want, i.e. it retrieves all entries from calendar with the matching lookup column. But in roughly 10% of requests it fails. It turns out, it depends on the content of the lookup column. I.e. if I want to filter for the item no 101 from custom list, I get an error, when I filter for ID 90, it works.

I use the ID of the custom list's element for ODATA filtering.

Raw input of a working sample:

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "GetItems"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work-here",
        "table": "Gruppenzuteilung",
        "$filter": "'90' eq Mitarbeiter/ID",
        "$orderby": "EndDate desc"
    }
}
```

Example not working:

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "GetItems"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work-here",
        "table": "Gruppenzuteilung",
        "$filter": "'101' eq Mitarbeiter/ID",
        "$orderby": "EndDate desc"
    }
}
```

Here the field **Mitarbeiter** is the lookup column in the calendar **Gruppenzuteilung**.

Now the error message is strange:

```
Die API "sharepointonline" hat eine ungültige Antwort für Workflowvorgang "Get_items" vom Typ "OpenApiConnection" zurückgegeben. 
Fehlerdetails: "Im API-Vorgang "GetItems" fehlt die erforderliche Eigenschaft "body/value/1/Title"."
```

Rough translation: "GetItems" is missing a needed property "body/value/1/Title"

As can be seen, there's no visible difference between the two requests. The filtering does only use this single column and additional sorting is done by $orderby.

Comment: I suppose for sure you have checked the title field of those two items (90 and 101) :) Any other differences between those two items on the list? Any hidden columns missing some info or similar? That would be my first place to look.

Comment: @RuneBH: I can't see anything significant in the Title fields of both lists. But what's that "1" inside "body/value/1/Title"? What does it refer to?

Comment: Oh my goodness. I found the problem. It's so stupid I can't believe it. I'll write an answer. But @RuneBH gave me a vital hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution, but the root cause is revealed.

After reconsidering RuneBH's hint, I double checked a lot to get behind this issue.

Finally it hasn't anything to do with the lookup, but wait it's not completely unrelated.

Root cause is: In the calendar, which I want to access with *GetItems* there were Items with Title not set (i.e. empty string). Title is a mandatory field, as it is inherited from the event content type.

Interestingly GetItems refuses to return items having mandatory fields with no content. I don't understand why sharepoint does this, because it is extremely cumbersome and if you wanted to repair those items from within a flow it would be a big hassle if you cannot fetch the content in advance.

So the error was returned when GetItems found one or more items where Title wasn't set. This had nothing to do with the ID's from the lookup column, except that it were accidentaly some IDs which had matched the lookup column in the calender returning events with no title.

I know there's always the possibility that items can accidentaly lack mandatory columns. But why did I miss that point?

Items with no title set don't show an empty column in calendar. They show "Kein Titel" or "No title" in the English version, **when they are not set.**

Unfortunately nobody needed the "Title" column and the default Value "Kein Titel" was selected for new items. So in the list view I could not see the difference and thought all items had the string "Kein Titel" in the "Title" column.

I found out, when I started to filter the Title column and saw that there was the (empty) option to select.

Test:
I added some title content in the respective item and the flow finishes flawlessly.

However: I changed the Title field to optional, but this didn't fix the problem. I'll write a new question concerning that.