# Another strange error on GetItems. Missing parameter error, although column isn't mandatory

Tags: content-type, flow, power-automate

This question relates to some strange behaviour of GetItems on a list namely a calendar. I got an error message complaining about an unfilled mandatory column  when I issued a GetItems request which would retrieve items having empty mandatory columns. It was difficult to find out what happened as I described in my first question and answer here:

[First part of my problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299805/strange-error-on-getitems-missing-parameter-depending-on-item)

The solution was to fill all mandatory fields. However only Microsoft knows, why

- it's even possible to create items leaving mandatory fields empty (I know that it was always mandatory until now)
- GetItems makes a fuzz while only reading the content of the items. It could just deliver the data.

Having this said, I thought that I could set the mandatory field to optional and be fine. Wrong, the flow still complains about the same issue. Whenever the field which used to be mandatory is empty the error is thrown.

It must have to do with the content type. All items in the calendar aren't of type "Event" but of a content type derived from "Event". I did that, as I had to add several columns and I also wanted to hide several other columns from users, so they didn't show up in forms. So of course, the column Title was inherited from "Event" in my new content type. When looking at the site content type "Event", Title is of course mandatory, and I don't want to change the original site content types.

Somehow GetItems must be thinking that the items are of "Event" content type and not my derived content type. That's my explanation for the behaviour, but I'd like to have it more precise so I can deal with it better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since converting the fields to optional, have you opened and re-saved the flow? It might be storing 'some schema' of the list (content type & fields) and remember the previous state of the fields as required.

Comment: Tried that, didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: 1) Lists hold their own copies of columns, so you can change the Title column on that specific calendar to be optional without changing the original Title column at the site level. 2) Content types can have their columns set to mandatory/optional independently of the setting on the actual column, so there can be a disconnect there - maybe a column is set to optional in the content type def. but is required if you look at it directly from the list columns? Or vice versa (optional on the actual column, but required in the content type)? Something to look at.

Comment: I set the column to optional in all list content types available. Behaviour is persistent. I'm continuing my search.